# Where to enter git commands?

Tags: git, command-line

I'm pretty sure this will be a basic question for a lot of people, but here goes:

I started going through the book "Pro Git", and it says to start by setting my username and email using the following lines:

`$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"`

`$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

Where do I type these lines? I tried typing them into command prompt and the git GUI, but I've had no success. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Can you expatiate on "no success"? Did you get an error? Is `git` in your `%PATH%`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assuming you've probably installed the windows git from http://git-scm.com/download/win

With the very defaults that won't put git on your command prompt.

Use 'git bash' either through the start menu or right clicking in the folder.

Comment: That did it. In hindsight, I feel like it should have been obvious, but thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 3):

Press 'Start' button in Windows, type 'cmd' in the search field on the bottom of menu. There you have the command line console. Try to type `git --version`, if show something like 'git version 1.8.0.2', you're ready to input all the commands here.

For those command you wrote like`$ git xxxxxx`, just ignore the `$` sign of begin, it's something like `C:\>` for unix like OSs.